# Python: If Condition then skip to return

Tags: python, return, indentation

I wondered if there is a nice way to tell the python interpreter to **skip to the next/last return statement of a function**.

Lets assume the following dummy code:

```py
def foo(bar):
  do(stuff)

  if condition:
    do(stuff)
    if condition2:
      do(stuff)
      if condition3:
        ...

  return (...)
```

Sometimes this gets really messy with many conditions that i cant chain because they rely on on the block `do(stuff)` above. I could now do this:

```py
def foo(bar):
  do(stuff)

  if not condition: return (...)
  do(stuff)
  if not condition2: return (...)
  do(stuff)
  if not condition3: return (...)
    ...

  return (...)
```

It looks a little less messy but i would have to repeat the return statement again and again which is somwhat anoying and if its a long tuple or similar it even looks worse.
The perfect solution would be to say "if not condition, skip to the final return statement". Is this somehow possible?

**edit:** to make this clear: my goal is to improve readability while avoiding a drop in performance

Comment: _"somewhat annoying and if its a long tuple"_. Can't you just do `x = [insert long tuple here]`? Then you can return it in lots of places and you only have to write `return x` each time.

Comment: Generally, if you ever find your code moving over to the right more and more due to nested statements, there's always a way to restructure the entire logic. How exactly depends on the concrete thing you're doing and how those actions and conditions can be simplified. There's no real generic answer.

Comment: What about about using the *try else* **finally** construct and then doing regular *returns*. finally is usually meant to close resources, but you can perform some household chores as per your meaning by the *final return statement*.  Not sure if you can return something different there, but I don't see why not.  Don't disagree that there is a bit of code smell to your setup, but we don't know about your logic and I find your question a valid one on its own.

Comment: Ps have you thought of writing some simple *executable* code that shows your intent?  Could be as simple as 2 or 3 args getting tested and one of the upper cond blocks mutating an arg.

Answer (score 5):

I think I would create a list of functions (I assume that all the `do(stuff)` in your example are actually different functions). Then you can use a `for` loop:

```
list_of_funcs = [func1, func2, func3]
for func in list_of_funcs:
    func(stuff)
    if not condition:
        break
return (...)
```

If the conditions are different then you can also create a list of conditions (which will be a list of functions that return `True` or `False`), then you can use `zip` in the following manner:

```
list_of_funcs = [func1, func2, func3]
list_of_conditions = [cond1, cond2, cond3]
for func, cond in zip(list_of_funcs, list_of_conditions):
    func(stuff)
    if not cond():
        break
return (...)
```

This way your actual code stays the same length and in the same indentation level, no matter how many functions and conditions you may have.

Comment: I think you can remove the first part - the conditions are definitely different. Otherwise, the question wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Indeed the conditions are different... while your way to do it may work and solve the problem of indentation, it does not really improve readability in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this:

```py
def foo(bar):

  for __ in [0]:
     do(stuff)

     if not condition: continue
     do(stuff)
     if not condition2: continue
     do(stuff)
     if not condition3: continue
     ...

  return (...)
```

Or possibly:

```py
def foo(bar):

  while True:
     do(stuff)

     if not condition: break
     do(stuff)
     if not condition2: break
     do(stuff)
     if not condition3: break
     ...
     break
  return (...)
```

It's a bit cleaner and avoids having multiple returns :+1: From the two the first one may be better as it explicitly shows that there is no intention on looping.

Answer (score -1):

Refactoring your code is a *much* better idea than what I am about to suggest, but this is an option.

```
class GotoEnd(Exception):
    pass

def foo(bar):

  try:
    do(stuff)
    if not condition: raise GotoEnd
    do(stuff)
    if not condition2: raise GotoEnd

    do(stuff)
    if not condition3: raise GotoEnd

    ...
  except GotoEnd:
    pass

  return (...)
```

Comment: Good idea but if an exception occurs, in do(stuff) for example, it will be ignored and return wil be executed

Comment: Good point; I think I want `else` instead of `finally`, so that the `return` only executes in the absence of any other uncaught exceptions?

Comment: With else the return won't be executed in case Exception is raised.  I would define a specific exception (e.g. `class GotoException(Exception): pass`) and replace `raise Exception` by `raise GotoException()` and `finally:` or `else:` by `except GotoException:`, which would only contain `pass`. And the return would stay the last line.

Comment: That's true in the original code, too. An uncaught exception would cause `foo` to exit immediately. I did have a `GotoEnd` exception in my initial draft, but cut it as strictly unnecessary. It would make it easier to ensure it isn't accidentally caught by any existing exception handling in a real example, but in this generic code, the exception is only raised in the context of the outermost `try` block.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure I may have re-implemented something you can accomplish with a trivial use of an `ExitStack` context manager.

Comment: Also also, I probably shouldn't try too hard to defend this approach; if this is an easier solution than refactoring your code, then your code *really* needs refactoring.

Comment: In the original code an uncaught exception would cause `foo` to exit immediately, but with an exception raised.